# Прокси на Python'e с сохранением исходного IP

Tags: python

День добрый. Пытаюсь написать прокси для переброса всего трафика на другой сервер без потери IP'a клиентов.
Нашел довольно годную основу, но не знаю как сделать сохранение IP.
Думаю, нужно как-то подменять src_ip, но как?
Подскажите пожалуйста)

```
import socket
import select
import time
import sys

buffer_size = 4096
delay = 0.01
forward_to = ("КУДА_НАПРАВЛЯТЬ", 7777)

class Forward:
    def __init__(self):
        self.forward = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.forward.connect((host, port))
            return self.forward
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return False

class TheServer:
    input_list = []
    channel = {}

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        self.server.listen(200)

    def main_loop(self):
        print "Starting redirect..."
        self.input_list.append(self.server)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(delay)
            ss = select.select
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])
            for self.s in inputready:
                if self.s == self.server:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break

                self.data = self.s.recv(buffer_size)
                if len(self.data) == 0:
                    self.on_close()
                    break
                else:
                    self.on_recv()

    def on_accept(self):
        forward = Forward().start(forward_to[0], forward_to[1])
        clientsock, clientaddr = self.server.accept()
        if forward:
            print clientaddr, "has connected"
            self.input_list.append(clientsock)
            self.input_list.append(forward)
            self.channel[clientsock] = forward
            self.channel[forward] = clientsock
        else:
            print "Can't establish connection with remote server.",
            print "Closing connection with client side", clientaddr
            clientsock.close()

    def on_close(self):
        self.input_list.remove(self.s)
        self.input_list.remove(self.channel[self.s])
        out = self.channel[self.s]
        self.channel[out].close()
        self.channel[self.s].close()
        del self.channel[out]
        del self.channel[self.s]

    def on_recv(self):
         data = self.data
         self.channel[self.s].send(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        server = TheServer('', 7777)
        try:
            server.main_loop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Stopping proxy server.."
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Никак. Прокси не может использовать ip клиента как свой. Он может только послать заголовок вида X-Forwarded-For и передать там ip клиента

Comment: Это возможно только манипуляцией IP-пакетами на уровне ОС или в роутере (iptables?), сокетами такое сделать невозможно

Comment: Хорошо, тогда не подскажешь, как именно? Способы с iptables которые я пробовал также не сохраняют IP.

Comment: Если вы измените IP на ip клиента, то принимающая сторона ответные пакеты (А они в любом случае будут, потому как прием информации всегда подтвержается) будет слать напрямую на тот ip минуя вас. Но клиент, (даже если у него реальный ip), получив такой ответный пакет, просто его выбросит, потому, что он прямого запроса от себя не посылал. Поэтому отправка любых пакетов с ip, которых нет на хосте с вашей программой не имеет смысла

Comment: Похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044): какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить, пытаясь подменять ip proxy? Вы можете обновить ваш вопрос и указать какой более широкий контекст у задачи.

Comment: Если очень хочется, то [можно заменить ip](http://stackoverflow.com/q/414025/4279), но это из области хакерства, а не proxy.